# Downloadable graphics - SVG vs Canvas element?

Tags: javascript, graphics, canvas, svg

Is there a Javascript-y way to provide a downloadable link for a Canvas element? How about SVG graphics? And what if you also include a server-side script (not preferred, but if that's the only way...)?

Comment: So in the <a> link it points to something that will be a canvas element or an SVG graphic?  Can you go into more detail please, as this is very vague.  Also, why not just have the javascript d/l the javascript snippet that will draw the graphic?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to offer a "download the image" link for SVGs and Canvases, in png / gif / jpg format.  Znarkus answered the Canvas side of the question.  What about for a graphic made up of SVG elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried this, but it occurred to me that you might be able to use a [data URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to accomplish this. In theory you would use JS to generate the image pixel data needed, then insert that into the `href` of a link. Not sure that this will work though.

Example of a data URL:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you pass the data as a `POST` method as you will run into size constraints for a URL very quickly, by using Znarkus's approach.

But for SVG you can use an API, such as Batik (http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/).  For an example of how to do this you can follow these suggestions:

http://www.ehow.com/how_4764609_convert-svg-file-png-format.html

But, for this `POST` is your best bet also, which would be an ajax call to get the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
location.href = document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL()
```